# Create React App - build to a single output file

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I use CRA. I build my project using `yarn build`.
Is it possible to configure Webpack or whatever so that it will output a single .js file and not a bunch of them?

Comment: what is the output files?

Comment: Currently, multiple files named similar to "6.5c699bde.chunk.js",  "39.63268ab8.chunk.js"

Comment: You should disable code splitting.